# XML To MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql

Hi All and apologies if the question seems too trivial,

I am trying to save an XML data to a MySQL 5.0 data base. I am using the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\user1\\My Documents\\ArtifactData.xml'
INTO TABLE test_case
```

This loads the data to the table, but all fields are treated as the first column only, and not broken down into proper columns. Here is a sample xml tag.

```
<test_case>
            <module_id_test_case_id>test case id</module_id_test_case_id>
            <description>Some description</description>
            <design_complexity>Low</design_complexity>
            <execution_status>Pass</execution_status>
</test_case>
```

Here are the columns of the sample test_case table I am working with.
module_id_test_case_id,description,design_complexity,execution_status

After reading the file, all the fields are persisted as module_id_test_case_id, even data under description, design_complexity and execution_status tags.

When I use ROWS IDENTIFIED BY <>, there is a SQL syntax error thrown.

Can somebody please advice me on how to solve this isse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use LOAD DATA INFILE to load XML data in that way.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

look here for how to import data from xml
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing